# How to activated object again in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I created a dot following my mouse around in 2D and I created a cube object changing position on x and y. Now when I point my mouse to cube, it deactivates I set that, and now I want to activate it again. I try on trigger exit, but it didn't work.

```
public GameObject tapObject;
private float respawnTime = 1f;
public float xMin;
public float xMax;
public float yMin;
public float yMax;

void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(spawnEnemyTime());
}   

private void RandomSpawnObject()
{
    tapObject.transform.position = new Vector2(Random.Range(xMin, xMax), Random.Range(yMin, yMax));   
}
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    tapObject.SetActive(false);
}

IEnumerator spawnEnemyTime()
{
    while (true)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(respawnTime);
        RandomSpawnObject(); 
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am just going to repeat what everyone else here said:

A inactive object in Unity is **truly inactive**, meaning it does not receive any updates, can't collide with stuff and all the MonoBehaviour stuff that usually calls your code does not work either. You have to manually re-activate the object using a reference that you cached somewhere.

***But***, instead of just flat out disabling the whole object you could **disable the components** that you don't want to be active.

Example:

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    tapObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled = false;
}

private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    tapObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled = true;
}
```

This only deactivates your renderer component but leaves everything else as it is. So your object can still collide and it's still registered via e.g. `OnTriggerExit`.

Keep in mind that `GetComponent<T>()` is a **pretty expensive operation** so caching your component references is a good idea. The best solution would be to start out with a reference by creating a variable for it and assign it in the inspector.

Example:

```
//Set in inspector
public Renderer renderer

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    renderer.enabled = false;
}

private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    renderer.enabled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Once inactive the scripts on that object are not executed anymore => messages like `OnTriggerExit` are not called/executed.

One solution is to simply wrap the target object in a parent object and attach your script to the parent instead but make it (de)activate the child.

So the parent stays active and receives the message.

Comment: As an addendum, any script with a reference to that gameobject can activate/deactivate it. The parent strategy is a very good way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

When a GameObject is **not active** in Unity , **you can't click it**(no rendering,no colliding , nothing )

But ,You can create a hotkey (*new script or in other script*) , that can set it back to active , if it is not active.

Answer (score 0):

public GameObject GO;

Use GO.setactive(true); 
whereas  gameobject is the object use to define the specific thing or object which needs to be active and the whole code needs to written in the method "spawnEnemyTime" so that it could be get active after the specific time period

Answer (score 0):

You can just use an empty GameObject and get a reference the object that you want to enable/disable. If you get the reference before you disable it you will be able to activate it again.

the alternative is to do what TehMightyPotato said. Disable components it's actually the best way to solve this problem, but if you have lot's of components/subcomponents disable the gameobjects is faster.